# Что это за синтаксис в передаче параметра - "new object[] {s}"

Tags: c#

```
string s= bbb.EndInvoke(ar);

BeginInvoke(new MyDelegat(PrintThat), new object[] {s});
```

Интересует - `,new object[] {s})`
Почему `s` в фигурных скобках?

Answer (score 15):

В этом выражении

```
new object[] {s}
```

создается массив объектов из одного элемента, который инициализируется строкой `s`. В результате ссылка на этот массив передается в качестве второго аргумента в вызов метода `BeginInvoke`

```
BeginInvoke( new MyDelegat(PrintThat), new object[] {s} );
```

Это более наглядно видно из объявлений массивов. Например,

```
string s = "Hello";

object[] a = new object[] { s };
object[] a1 = new object[1] { s };
object[] a2 = { s };
```

Или такое объявление массива и вывод его элементов на консоль

```
object[] a = new object[] { "Hello", "World" };

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}!", a[0], a[1]);
```

В этом случае будет создан массив с двумя элементами по числу инициализаторов.

Для полноты картины можете выполнить следующий фрагмент кода

```
string s = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine(new object[] { s }[0]);
```

На консоль будет выведена строка `"Hello"`.

Comment: в дополнение: тип элементов в такой записи можно опускать, и тогда он будет выведен компилятором, как самый общий для указанных элементов.